# Elasticsearch does not see static scripts?

Tags: java, search, groovy, elasticsearch, search-engine

Get a strange behavior of my Elasticsearch cluster: seems that it does not see static groovy scripts any more.

It complains that "dynamic scripting is disabled", however I am using stating script and correct name of it.

They did work before, and now can't understand what was changed.

Here are steps I am using to reproduce the problem:

Create index with mapping defining one string field and on nested object:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/ -d '{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_mapping/testtype -d '{
  "testtype": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "features": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

response:

```
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

Put a single object there:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/testtype/1 -d '{
  "name": "hello",
  "features": []
}'
```

Call update using the script:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/testtype/1/_update -d '{
  "script": "add-feature-if-not-exists",
  "params": {
    "new_feature": {
      "key": "Manufacturer",
      "value": "China"
    }
  }
}'
```

response:

```
{
  "error": "RemoteTransportException[[esnew1][inet[/78.46.100.39:9300]][indices:data/write/update]];
              nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; 
              nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

Getting "dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled" - but I am using a reference to static script name in "script" field. However I've seen this message occurring if the name of script was incorrect. But looks like it is correct:

The script is located in /etc/elasticsearch/scripts/ .
Verifying that /etc/elasticsearch is used as a config directory:

```
ps aux | grep elas
elastic+   944  0.8  4.0 21523740 1322820 ?    Sl   15:35   0:39 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Xms16g -Xmx16g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp :/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-1.4.0.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* -Des.default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

Looking if script is there:

```
$ ls -l /etc/elasticsearch/   total 24   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13683 Nov 25 14:52 elasticsearch.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1511 Nov 15 04:13 logging.yml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 25 15:07 scripts


$ ls -l /etc/elasticsearch/scripts/   total 8   -rw-r--r-- 1
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 438 Nov 25 15:07 add-feature-if-not-exists.groovy
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 506 Nov 23 02:52 add-review-if-not-exists.groovy
```

Any hints on why this is happening? What else have I check?

Update: cluster has two nodes.

Config on node1:

```
cluster.name: myclustername
node.name: "esnew1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
network.host: zz.zz.zz.zz
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["esnew1.company.com","esnew2.company.com"]
index.store.type: niofs
script.disable_dynamic: true
script.auto_reload_enabled: true
watcher.interval: 30s
```

Config on node 2:

```
cluster.name: myclustername
node.name: "esnew2"
node.master: true
node.data: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
metwork.bind_host: 127.0.0.1,zz.zz.zz.zz
network.publish_host: zz.zz.zz.zz
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["esnew1.company.com","esnew2.company.com"]
index.store.type: niofs
script.disable_dynamic: true
script.auto_reload_enabled: true
watcher.interval: 30s
```

Elasticsearch version:

```
$ curl localhost:9200
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "esnew2",
  "cluster_name" : "myclustername",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "bc94bd81298f81c656893ab1ddddd30a99356066",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-11-05T14:26:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

P.S.: One observation confirming that probably ES just don't see the scripts: at some moment, ES was seeing one script, but did not see another. After restart it does not see none of them.

P.P.S.: The script:

```
do_add = false

def stringsEqual(s1, s2) {
   if (s1 == null) {
      return s2 == null;
   }
   return s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2);
}
for (item in ctx._source.features) {
    if (stringsEqual(item['key'], new_feature.key) {
        if (! stringsEqual(item['value'], new_feature.value) {  
            item.value = new_feature.value;
        }
    } else {  
      do_add = true
    }  
}  
if (do_add) {
    ctx._source.features.add(new_feature)
}
```

Comment: Did you upgrade recently?

Comment: @AndreiStefan No, I did not. And this is unlikely that somebody else did it.

Comment: Can you share the script, please?

Comment: Added the script to question. And it is looking strange to me: if I change script to empty one, the update does complete (in case of syntax errors in script, it was complaining in the output explaining what is wrong).

Comment: the above script has syntax errors  missing parenthesis line 10 and 11  i.e. `(stringsEqual(item['key'], new_feature.key)`  and  if `(! stringsEqual(item['value'], new_feature.value)`

Comment: @keety As I see now, the error is in script itself. But can I see the errors produced by Groovy somewhere (syntax errors /runtime errors)?

Comment: @AlexTigarev you should be able to see the compilation/runtime errors in the elasticsearch log files . Besides the syntax error i don't think method definitions are allowed in elasticsearch

Comment: Yeah, seeing SecurityException in logs. Thanks!